# Displaying selections to an SVG rectangle (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I saw [this post last night](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848280/property-map-of-undefined-javascript) and wanted to replicate it/make it better - because it interested me. However, I'm stuck on displaying the selections to an SVG rectangle. I thought by appending text to the function where the Lasso is called would work, however it doesn't. I've included the problematic code and would like to know where I've gone wrong for me to improve. Thanks.

If you need anymore code, holla.

```
var textBox = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(5,385)");

textBox.append("rect")
        .attr("height", 10)
        .attr("width", 100)
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke-width", 1);

        var lasso_start = function() {
        lasso.items()
            .attr("r",7) 
            .classed("not_possible",true)
            .classed("selected",false);
};

var lasso_draw = function() {

        lasso.possibleItems()
            .classed("not_possible",false)
            .classed("possible",true);

        lasso.notPossibleItems()
            .classed("not_possible",true)
            .classed("possible",false);
};

var lasso_end = function() {

        lasso.items()
            .classed("not_possible",false)
            .classed("possible",false);

        selected = lasso.selectedItems()
            .classed("selected", true)
            .attr("r", 13);

        var selectedDots = selected.data().map(d=>d[0]);

};

var lasso = d3.lasso()
        .closePathSelect(true)
        .closePathDistance(100)
        .items(circles)
        .targetArea(area)
        .on("start",lasso_start)
        .on("draw",lasso_draw)
        .on("end",function(d) {
            textBox.append("text")
                .attr("x", 10)
                .attr("y", 20)
                .text(lasso_end)
});

svg.call(lasso);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the [block](https://bl.ocks.org/shashank2104/f878d660bd9013faa6d48236b5fe9502/67d50a5c7a21c0adfa5ed66ce3dc725f0a45c8c2) that I posted as an answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755677/lasso-and-d3-js) to include the selections in a rect, here's a fork for the same:

https://bl.ocks.org/shashank2104/d58381c96971ff131c03e8832470085b/151651c9fa3e94fef46e243227924f4e4c90cf01

And a code snippet if that's convenient:

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300');
 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300");
 text {
     font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
}
 .axis path {
     stroke: black;
}
 .tick line {
     visibility: hidden;
}
 .border {
     margin-top: 9px;
     margin-left: 29px;
     border: .5px solid black;
     width: 325px;
     height: 335px;
     position: absolute;
}
 .lasso path {
     stroke: rgb(80,80,80);
     stroke-width:2px;
}
 .lasso .drawn {
     fill-opacity:.05 ;
}
 .lasso .loop_close {
     fill:none;
     stroke-dasharray: 4, 4;
}
 .lasso .origin {
     fill:#3399FF;
     fill-opacity:.5;
}
 .not_possible {
     fill:rgb(200,200,200);
}
 .textBox rect {
     fill: steelblue;
}
 text.selection {
     font-size: 12px;
     fill: #FFF;
     letter-spacing: 0.1em;
     font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
!function(t,n){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?n(exports,require("d3-selection"),require("d3-drag")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["exports","d3-selection","d3-drag"],n):n(t.d3=t.d3||{},t.d3,t.d3)}(this,function(t,n,r){"use strict";function e(t,n){return n={exports:{}},t(n,n.exports),n.exports}function o(){function t(t){function u(){p=[],h="",_.attr("d",null),m.attr("d",null),r.nodes().forEach(function(t){t.__lasso.possible=!1,t.__lasso.selected=!1,t.__lasso.hoverSelect=!1,t.__lasso.loopSelect=!1;var n=t.getBoundingClientRect();t.__lasso.lassoPoint=[Math.round(n.left+n.width/2),Math.round(n.top+n.height/2)]}),s&&r.on("mouseover.lasso",function(){this.__lasso.hoverSelect=!0}),i.start()}function l(){var t,n;"touchmove"===d3.event.sourceEvent.type?(t=d3.event.sourceEvent.touches[0].clientX,n=d3.event.sourceEvent.touches[0].clientY):(t=d3.event.sourceEvent.clientX,n=d3.event.sourceEvent.clientY);var s=d3.mouse(this)[0],u=d3.mouse(this)[1];""===h?(h=h+"M "+s+" "+u,v=[t,n],d=[s,u],b.attr("cx",s).attr("cy",u).attr("r",7).attr("display",null)):h=h+" L "+s+" "+u,p.push([t,n]);var l=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(t-v[0],2)+Math.pow(n-v[1],2)),f="M "+s+" "+u+" L "+d[0]+" "+d[1];_.attr("d",h),m.attr("d",f),a=l<=e,a&&o?m.attr("display",null):m.attr("display","none"),r.nodes().forEach(function(t){t.__lasso.loopSelect=!(!a||!o)&&c(p,t.__lasso.lassoPoint)<1,t.__lasso.possible=t.__lasso.hoverSelect||t.__lasso.loopSelect}),i.draw()}function f(){r.on("mouseover.lasso",null),r.nodes().forEach(function(t){t.__lasso.selected=t.__lasso.possible,t.__lasso.possible=!1}),_.attr("d",null),m.attr("d",null),b.attr("display","none"),i.end()}var h,v,d,p,g=t.append("g").attr("class","lasso"),_=g.append("path").attr("class","drawn"),m=g.append("path").attr("class","loop_close"),b=g.append("circle").attr("class","origin"),M=d3.drag().on("start",u).on("drag",l).on("end",f);n.call(M)}var n,r=[],e=75,o=!0,a=!1,s=!0,i={start:function(){},draw:function(){},end:function(){}};return t.items=function(n){if(!arguments.length)return r;r=n;var e=r.nodes();return e.forEach(function(t){t.__lasso={possible:!1,selected:!1}}),t},t.possibleItems=function(){return r.filter(function(){return this.__lasso.possible})},t.selectedItems=function(){return r.filter(function(){return this.__lasso.selected})},t.notPossibleItems=function(){return r.filter(function(){return!this.__lasso.possible})},t.notSelectedItems=function(){return r.filter(function(){return!this.__lasso.selected})},t.closePathDistance=function(n){return arguments.length?(e=n,t):e},t.closePathSelect=function(n){return arguments.length?(o=n===!0,t):o},t.isPathClosed=function(n){return arguments.length?(a=n===!0,t):a},t.hoverSelect=function(n){return arguments.length?(s=n===!0,t):s},t.on=function(n,r){if(!arguments.length)return i;if(1===arguments.length)return i[n];var e=["start","draw","end"];return e.indexOf(n)>-1&&(i[n]=r),t},t.targetArea=function(r){return arguments.length?(n=r,t):n},t}var a=e(function(t){function n(t,n,e){var o=t*n,a=r*t,s=a-t,i=a-s,u=t-i,l=r*n,f=l-n,c=l-f,h=n-c,v=o-i*c,d=v-u*c,p=d-i*h,g=u*h-p;return e?(e[0]=g,e[1]=o,e):[g,o]}t.exports=n;var r=+(Math.pow(2,27)+1)}),s=e(function(t){function n(t,n){var r=t+n,e=r-t,o=r-e,a=n-e,s=t-o,i=s+a;return i?[i,r]:[r]}function r(t,r){var e=0|t.length,o=0|r.length;if(1===e&&1===o)return n(t[0],r[0]);var a,s,i=e+o,u=new Array(i),l=0,f=0,c=0,h=Math.abs,v=t[f],d=h(v),p=r[c],g=h(p);d<g?(s=v,f+=1,f<e&&(v=t[f],d=h(v))):(s=p,c+=1,c<o&&(p=r[c],g=h(p))),f<e&&d<g||c>=o?(a=v,f+=1,f<e&&(v=t[f],d=h(v))):(a=p,c+=1,c<o&&(p=r[c],g=h(p)));for(var _,m,b,M,y,w=a+s,x=w-a,j=s-x,E=j,A=w;f<e&&c<o;)d<g?(a=v,f+=1,f<e&&(v=t[f],d=h(v))):(a=p,c+=1,c<o&&(p=r[c],g=h(p))),s=E,w=a+s,x=w-a,j=s-x,j&&(u[l++]=j),_=A+w,m=_-A,b=_-m,M=w-m,y=A-b,E=y+M,A=_;for(;f<e;)a=v,s=E,w=a+s,x=w-a,j=s-x,j&&(u[l++]=j),_=A+w,m=_-A,b=_-m,M=w-m,y=A-b,E=y+M,A=_,f+=1,f<e&&(v=t[f]);for(;c<o;)a=p,s=E,w=a+s,x=w-a,j=s-x,j&&(u[l++]=j),_=A+w,m=_-A,b=_-m,M=w-m,y=A-b,E=y+M,A=_,c+=1,c<o&&(p=r[c]);return E&&(u[l++]=E),A&&(u[l++]=A),l||(u[l++]=0),u.length=l,u}t.exports=r}),i=e(function(t){function n(t,n,r){var e=t+n,o=e-t,a=e-o,s=n-o,i=t-a;return r?(r[0]=i+s,r[1]=e,r):[i+s,e]}t.exports=n}),u=e(function(t){function n(t,n){var o=t.length;if(1===o){var a=r(t[0],n);return a[0]?a:[a[1]]}var s=new Array(2*o),i=[.1,.1],u=[.1,.1],l=0;r(t[0],n,i),i[0]&&(s[l++]=i[0]);for(var f=1;f<o;++f){r(t[f],n,u);var c=i[1];e(c,u[0],i),i[0]&&(s[l++]=i[0]);var h=u[1],v=i[1],d=h+v,p=d-h,g=v-p;i[1]=d,g&&(s[l++]=g)}return i[1]&&(s[l++]=i[1]),0===l&&(s[l++]=0),s.length=l,s}var r=a,e=i;t.exports=n}),l=e(function(t){function n(t,n){var r=t+n,e=r-t,o=r-e,a=n-e,s=t-o,i=s+a;return i?[i,r]:[r]}function r(t,r){var e=0|t.length,o=0|r.length;if(1===e&&1===o)return n(t[0],-r[0]);var a,s,i=e+o,u=new Array(i),l=0,f=0,c=0,h=Math.abs,v=t[f],d=h(v),p=-r[c],g=h(p);d<g?(s=v,f+=1,f<e&&(v=t[f],d=h(v))):(s=p,c+=1,c<o&&(p=-r[c],g=h(p))),f<e&&d<g||c>=o?(a=v,f+=1,f<e&&(v=t[f],d=h(v))):(a=p,c+=1,c<o&&(p=-r[c],g=h(p)));for(var _,m,b,M,y,w=a+s,x=w-a,j=s-x,E=j,A=w;f<e&&c<o;)d<g?(a=v,f+=1,f<e&&(v=t[f],d=h(v))):(a=p,c+=1,c<o&&(p=-r[c],g=h(p))),s=E,w=a+s,x=w-a,j=s-x,j&&(u[l++]=j),_=A+w,m=_-A,b=_-m,M=w-m,y=A-b,E=y+M,A=_;for(;f<e;)a=v,s=E,w=a+s,x=w-a,j=s-x,j&&(u[l++]=j),_=A+w,m=_-A,b=_-m,M=w-m,y=A-b,E=y+M,A=_,f+=1,f<e&&(v=t[f]);for(;c<o;)a=p,s=E,w=a+s,x=w-a,j=s-x,j&&(u[l++]=j),_=A+w,m=_-A,b=_-m,M=w-m,y=A-b,E=y+M,A=_,c+=1,c<o&&(p=-r[c]);return E&&(u[l++]=E),A&&(u[l++]=A),l||(u[l++]=0),u.length=l,u}t.exports=r}),f=e(function(t){function n(t,n){for(var r=new Array(t.length-1),e=1;e<t.length;++e)for(var o=r[e-1]=new Array(t.length-1),a=0,s=0;a<t.length;++a)a!==n&&(o[s++]=t[e][a]);return r}function r(t){for(var n=new Array(t),r=0;r<t;++r){n[r]=new Array(t);for(var e=0;e<t;++e)n[r][e]=["m",e,"[",t-r-1,"]"].join("")}return n}function e(t){return 1&t?"-":""}function o(t){if(1===t.length)return t[0];if(2===t.length)return["sum(",t[0],",",t[1],")"].join("");var n=t.length>>1;return["sum(",o(t.slice(0,n)),",",o(t.slice(n)),")"].join("")}function i(t){if(2===t.length)return[["sum(prod(",t[0][0],",",t[1][1],"),prod(-",t[0][1],",",t[1][0],"))"].join("")];for(var r=[],a=0;a<t.length;++a)r.push(["scale(",o(i(n(t,a))),",",e(a),t[0][a],")"].join(""));return r}function f(t){for(var e=[],a=[],s=r(t),u=[],l=0;l<t;++l)0===(1&l)?e.push.apply(e,i(n(s,l))):a.push.apply(a,i(n(s,l))),u.push("m"+l);var f=o(e),c=o(a),h="orientation"+t+"Exact",_=["function ",h,"(",u.join(),"){var p=",f,",n=",c,",d=sub(p,n);return d[d.length-1];};return ",h].join(""),m=new Function("sum","prod","scale","sub",_);return m(d,v,p,g)}function c(t){var n=x[t.length];return n||(n=x[t.length]=f(t.length)),n.apply(void 0,t)}function h(){for(;x.length<=_;)x.push(f(x.length));for(var n=[],r=["slow"],e=0;e<=_;++e)n.push("a"+e),r.push("o"+e);for(var o=["function getOrientation(",n.join(),"){switch(arguments.length){case 0:case 1:return 0;"],e=2;e<=_;++e)o.push("case ",e,":return o",e,"(",n.slice(0,e).join(),");");o.push("}var s=new Array(arguments.length);for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;++i){s[i]=arguments[i]};return slow(s);}return getOrientation"),r.push(o.join(""));var a=Function.apply(void 0,r);t.exports=a.apply(void 0,[c].concat(x));for(var e=0;e<=_;++e)t.exports[e]=x[e]}var v=a,d=s,p=u,g=l,_=5,m=1.1102230246251565e-16,b=(3+16*m)*m,M=(7+56*m)*m,y=f(3),w=f(4),x=[function(){return 0},function(){return 0},function(t,n){return n[0]-t[0]},function(t,n,r){var e,o=(t[1]-r[1])*(n[0]-r[0]),a=(t[0]-r[0])*(n[1]-r[1]),s=o-a;if(o>0){if(a<=0)return s;e=o+a}else{if(!(o<0))return s;if(a>=0)return s;e=-(o+a)}var i=b*e;return s>=i||s<=-i?s:y(t,n,r)},function(t,n,r,e){var o=t[0]-e[0],a=n[0]-e[0],s=r[0]-e[0],i=t[1]-e[1],u=n[1]-e[1],l=r[1]-e[1],f=t[2]-e[2],c=n[2]-e[2],h=r[2]-e[2],v=a*l,d=s*u,p=s*i,g=o*l,_=o*u,m=a*i,b=f*(v-d)+c*(p-g)+h*(_-m),y=(Math.abs(v)+Math.abs(d))*Math.abs(f)+(Math.abs(p)+Math.abs(g))*Math.abs(c)+(Math.abs(_)+Math.abs(m))*Math.abs(h),x=M*y;return b>x||-b>x?b:w(t,n,r,e)}];h()}),c=e(function(t){function n(t,n){for(var e=n[0],o=n[1],a=t.length,s=1,i=a,u=0,l=a-1;u<i;l=u++){var f=t[u],c=t[l],h=f[1],v=c[1];if(v<h){if(v<o&&o<h){var d=r(f,c,n);if(0===d)return 0;s^=0<d|0}else if(o===h){var p=t[(u+1)%a],g=p[1];if(h<g){var d=r(f,c,n);if(0===d)return 0;s^=0<d|0}}}else if(h<v){if(h<o&&o<v){var d=r(f,c,n);if(0===d)return 0;s^=d<0|0}else if(o===h){var p=t[(u+1)%a],g=p[1];if(g<h){var d=r(f,c,n);if(0===d)return 0;s^=d<0|0}}}else if(o===h){var _=Math.min(f[0],c[0]),m=Math.max(f[0],c[0]);if(0===u){for(;l>0;){var b=(l+a-1)%a,M=t[b];if(M[1]!==o)break;var y=M[0];_=Math.min(_,y),m=Math.max(m,y),l=b}if(0===l)return _<=e&&e<=m?0:1;i=l+1}for(var w=t[(l+a-1)%a][1];u+1<i;){var M=t[u+1];if(M[1]!==o)break;var y=M[0];_=Math.min(_,y),m=Math.max(m,y),u+=1}if(_<=e&&e<=m)return 0;var x=t[(u+1)%a][1];e<_&&w<o!=x<o&&(s^=1)}}return 2*s-1}t.exports=n;var r=f});t.lasso=o,Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0})});</script>

</head>
<body>
   <script>
      var data = [["Arsenal",-0.0032967741593940836, 0.30399753945657115],["Chelsea", 0.2752159801936051, -0.0389675484210763], ["Liverpool",-0.005096951348655329, 0.026678627680541075], ["Manchester City",-0.004715381791104284, -0.12338379196523988], ["Manchester United",0.06877966010653305, -0.0850615090351779], ["Tottenham",-0.3379518099485709, -0.09933664174939877]];
      
      var selectedTeams = [];
      
      const colours = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .domain(data)
          .range(["#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D", "#2A363B"]);
      
      var canvasW = 675;
      var canvasH = 600;   
      var w = 365;
      var h = 365;
      var xPadding = 30;
      var yPadding = 20;
      var padding = 10;
      var border = 0.5;
      var bordercolor = 'black';
      
      var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([xPadding, w - padding])
          .domain([-1, 1]);
      
      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([h - yPadding, padding])
          .domain([-1, 1]);
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
          .append("svg")
          .attr('width', canvasW)
          .attr('height', canvasH);
      
      var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("r", 7)
          .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d[1]); })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[2]); })
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
            var result = null;
      
            if (data.indexOf(d) >= 0) {
              result = colours(d);
            } else {
              result = "white";
            }
            return result;               
          });
      
          var lasso_start = function() {
              lasso.items()
                  .attr("r",7) 
                  .classed("not_possible",true)
                  .classed("selected",false);
          };
      
          var lasso_draw = function() {
      
              lasso.possibleItems()
                  .classed("not_possible",false)
                  .classed("possible",true);
      
              lasso.notPossibleItems()
                  .classed("not_possible",true)
                  .classed("possible",false);
          };
      
        var modifyTextBox = function (selected) {
           if(selected.length) {
              var widths = [], textHeight = 0;
              var texts = textBox.selectAll('text.selection')
                .data(selected);
      
              texts.exit().remove();
      
              texts
               .enter().append('text').attr('class', 'selection').attr('x', '3')
               .merge(texts)
                .attr('y', function (d, i) {
                  return i * 13 + 12;
                }).text(function (d) { return d; });
                
          textBox.selectAll('text.selection')          
                .each(function (d) {
                  widths.push(d3.select(this).node().getBBox().width);
                  textHeight = d3.select(this).node().getBBox().height;
                });
      
              var maxW = selected.length ? d3.max(widths) : 0;
              textBox.style('display', null).select('rect').attr('width', maxW+10).attr('height', selected.length*textHeight);
            } else {
             textBox.style('display', 'none');
            }
          };
          
          var lasso_end = function() {
      
              lasso.items()
                  .classed("not_possible",false)
                  .classed("possible",false);
      
              var selected = lasso.selectedItems()
                  .classed("selected", true)
                  .attr("r", 13);
      
         var selectedDots = selected.data().map(d=>d[0]);
            modifyTextBox(selectedDots);
          };
      
          var textBox = svg.append("g").classed('textBox', true).style('display', 'none');
      
          textBox.append("rect")
                  .attr("height", 10)
                  .attr("width", 100)
                  .style("stroke-width", 1);
          
          var area = svg.append("rect")
              .attr("width", w)
              .attr("height", h)
              .style("opacity", 0);
      
          var lasso = d3.lasso()
              .closePathSelect(true)
              .closePathDistance(100)
              .items(circles)
              .targetArea(area)
              .on("start",lasso_start)
              .on("draw",lasso_draw)
              .on("end",lasso_end);
      
              var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                .data(colours.domain())
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "legend")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 29 + ")"; });
      
            legend.append("rect")
                .attr("x", canvasW - 184)
                .attr("y", 11)
                .attr("width", 18)
                .attr("height", 18)
                .style("fill", colours);
      
            legend.append("text")
                .attr("x", canvasW - 194)
                .attr("y", 20)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text(function(d) { return d[0];})
            
          svg.call(lasso);
      
       
       
   </script>
```

**Relevant changes:**

Based on the selections, I've added a function that adds texts to the `textBox` with an enter/exit/merge logic and assigns widths to the `rect` based on the maximum length of the text.

```
 var modifyTextBox = function (selected) {
        if(selected.length) {
          var widths = [], textHeight = 0;
          var texts = textBox.selectAll('text.selection')
            .data(selected);

          texts.exit().remove();

          texts
            .enter().append('text').attr('class', 'selection').attr('x', '3')
            .merge(texts)
            .attr('y', function (d, i) {
              return i * 13 + 12;
            }).text(function (d) { return d; });

          textBox.selectAll('text.selection')          
            .each(function (d) {
              widths.push(d3.select(this).node().getBBox().width);
              textHeight = d3.select(this).node().getBBox().height;
            });

          var maxW = selected.length ? d3.max(widths) : 0;
          textBox.style('display', null).select('rect').attr('width', maxW+10).attr('height', selected.length*textHeight);
        } else {
            textBox.style('display', 'none');
        }
      };
```

And calling this in the `lasso_end` function as: `modifyTextBox(selectedDots);`

And I've added some CSS for this textBox and the texts within it:

```
.textBox rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}
text.selection {
  font-size: 12px;
  fill: #FFF;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Feel free to play around with this function to position the rect (probably based on the mouse).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, a very elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)